# How to install Velero with helm and with Azure Managed Identity?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

So, I have followed the documentation in:

1. https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-microsoft-azure#option-2-use-aad-pod-identity
2. https://velero.io/docs/v1.5/basic-install/

And I am still at a loss of how do I install Velero using its helm chart at https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/helm-charts, because I cannot reconcile the helm chart based installation with what is documented in
https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-microsoft-azure

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Installed https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity. Validated that it works.
2. Created Azure Storage Container in a dedicated Storage Account for the backups
3. Created an MSI to be used by Velero as explained in https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-microsoft-azure#option-2-use-aad-pod-identity

Now I need to update the [values.yaml](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/velero/values.yaml) file, but I am stuck at the credentials section. I am unable to reconcile the `velero install` instructions given on https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-microsoft-azure with what I see in the values.yaml file.

E.g. I have created the `credentials-velero` file:

```
AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=...
AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP=...
AZURE_CLOUD_NAME=AzurePublicCloud
```

Of course, it does not contain the MSI credentials and the MSI name would be associated using the dedicated label. The [doc](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-microsoft-azure#install-and-start-velero) says clearly:

> If you're using AAD Pod Identity, you now need to add the
> aadpodidbinding=$IDENTITY_NAME label to the Velero pod(s), preferably
> through the Deployment's pod template.

But how do I do it when I install Velero using a helm chart?

Answer (score 0):

Add the AzureIdentity and AzureIdentityBinding roles to cluster as mentioned in docs.

```
# Under AzureIdentityBinding
apiVersion: "aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1"
kind: AzureIdentityBinding
metadata:
  name: <name> #replace name
spec:
AzureIdentity: <identity> #replace with the name of the identity resource created.
Selector: <label>
```

once done, use the selector defined AzureIdentityBinding as label while deploying helm chart.

```
podLabels: {aadpodidbinding: <selector>} # selector you defined above in AzureIdentityBinding
```

Check for the actual syntax for podLabels using with --set in helm install command. Or you can clone the charts and make changes to values.yaml below and install it from local charts.

https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/helm-charts/blob/04615803a7d976ce15a6eeb4b1bd6a1cfb9a02c5/charts/velero/values.yaml#L27

Just for help:
https://medium.com/@kimvisscher/using-aad-pod-identity-in-an-aks-cluster-117c08565692