# Helm through Ansible on AKS with managed identitiy

Tags: azure, ansible, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

Is it possible to use the `helm` Ansible module to install into an AKS cluster that uses managed identities? That is, without doing `az login` before every Ansible run on the control node. The point is to make it purely automated. The helm module can use certs and http auth, but it doesn't look like AKS exposes either when using managed identity

Answer (score 0):

You have to ***configure [`AADPodBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-azure-ad-pod-identity) in AKS for using Helm without `azlogin`***. In order to set that you will ***need to configure the Azure Idenity*** which you have already enabled and then ***set binding for Azure Identity (i.e. Configure `AzureIdentityBinding`)***  . ***After the above is done, you can use the managed identity as a  service connection to used by helm deploy .***

***You can refer the below documents to get an idea on the same :***

- [`How-To: Deploy Microservice Application with Pod Identity Using Helm Chart`](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/how-to-deploy-microservice-application-with-pod-identity-using/ba-p/2268999)
- [`SO thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64327529/how-to-install-velero-with-helm-and-with-azure-managed-identity)

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't you still need to use `az login` to populate the .kube/config file that helm looks for? Even with the managed identity? Helm could be configured for the ID but it still needs to know about the cluster.